# How do I create a home button in the top right hand side of my UINavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

How do I create a home button in the top right hand side of my UINavigationControl.  Please note that I have instantiated my UINavigationControl on my second UIviewController named:  ViewControllerSecond.  I want to be able to have the tradition "Home" icon, and when pressed to resign back to my first UIviewControler within the appDelegate named:  ViewController.

I've got this far:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIBarButtonItem *homeProperty;

UIBarButtonItem *homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(home)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:homeButton animated:NO];
```

But I cant link it with my first ViewController or replace the text with a home button image.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also need the answer to this question as i couldn't find an answer to this question anywhere else.I would hav voteup'd this question if i had 15 repu :(
btw i want the selected items in my tableview to be posted on a new view controller when the "done" button on my top-right navigational bar gets clicked.I have also reached the same distance as the asker of this question.
Forgive me for posting my words in the answer section to this question as i can't post in comments to that question due to that 50 repu :(

EDIT:I think i found an answer,try this plz
     Since you hav action:@selector(home) so your method name will be:

```
- (IBAction)home:(id)sender {
//statements to execute
}
```

You don't have to link this method with anything as you have already declared this method as selector while declaring that "home" button.Neglect the open linkage in front of your method.
http://prntscr.com/1tc0q9